# Unable to remove an (bound) event listener

Tags: javascript

I am a newbie on javascript and I am encountering the following problem, which I wasn't able to find in previous answers after searching multiple times (hope this is not a duplicate).

I have the following module/class. Let's suppose that I am trying to implement a component which can be dragged around the screen. When the **user clicks on it the first time**, we start to listen to the `mousemove` events of the `window` to know where the user is moving the mouse to. Once the user releases the mouse, we want to remove the event listeners of the window. 
The code is quite straight forward, and it works if I just code it outside of an iife. However, currently the **`removeEventListener` simply does not work**. I guess it might have something to do with the *clousure*, the *scope* or something, but I am totally missing it. Thank you very much in advance, here is the code:

*MyClass.js*

```
 var myNamespace = myNamespace || {};
 (function(myNamespace){

 var onMouseDragDown = function(e){
          window.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseDragMove,true);
          window.addEventListener("mouseup", onMouseDragUp,false);
       };

  var onMouseDragUp = function(e){
// This code executes, but the events CONTINUE to be triggered after removing the event listener

//The following lines do not seem to have any effect whatsoever even though they are executed when the user releases the mouse button
      window.removeEventListener("mousemove", onMouseDragMove, true);
      window.removeEventListener("mouseup", onMouseDragUp,false);
  };

  var onMouseDragMove = function(e){
      console.log('moving');
   };

   myNamespace.MyClass = function(param){
      this._param = param;
      this._div = document.createElement('div');  
      this._div = ....

      this._div.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDragDown.bind(this), false);
   }

   myNameSpace.MyClass.prototype.getDiv = function (){
      return this._div;
   }
)(myNameSpace);
```

*Index.html*

...

```
        function onCreateNewDocumentClicked(event){
            var myObject = new myNamepace.MyClass(someParams);
            document.body.appendChild(mdi.getDiv());
        }
```

Comment: the code snippet is incomplete, i have no idea where you execute this code. by using `var onMouseDragDown = function(...)` , the code inside that function body won't be executed

Comment: I've edited the code so that you can see how I am creating an object of MyClass from the index.html. The code of named functions (var onMouseDragMove) does execute, only that the event continues to be triggered even after executing the wind.removeEventListener....

Comment: i see, then you probably should add `this._div.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseDragUp .bind(this), false);` in your `myNamespace.MyClass` definition

Comment: I can't really agree with that. As soon as the user clicks on the div, I add a listener to the window for the event `mouseup`. The listener works, since the code on that listener's function does execute. The problem is that REMOVING the event inside of the mouseup hanlder doesn't seem to do anything, as it keeps on being triggered, as well as the `mousemove`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove an event listener, you must provide the exact function that you provided when adding it.
What's happening here is that bind() creates a new function each time, so in fact :

```
someFunc.bind(someObj) !== someFunc.bind(someObj)
```

to remove an event listener, you have to store the very function that you provided when adding it.

so store the listener when you add it to be able to remove it later :

```
var someListener = someFunc.bind(someObj);
element.addEventListener("--", someListener ) ;

// then, later :
element.removeEventListener('--', someListener);
```

i made a short demo here, when you click on first button it will alert 'hello'.
We see that by removing the listener with a new call to bind, it doesn't remove it.
Then removing the stored function does the job.

http://jsbin.com/EjevIQA/2/edit

Edit : you don't need to add / remove a listener to each div you want dragged.
instead, you could just listen to click within the window, and make use of the 'target' 
information of the event, which will tell which div was clicked.
Maybe you'll want to stop propagation / prevent default when it is a handled
div which is clicked, i don't know.

the event handler will look like :

```
 function handleMouseDown(e) {
     // you might check here which button was clicked (0=left, 2=right)
     var button = e.button;
     // retrieve the target
     var target = e.target ;
     // check if the target is an object we want to drag
     ...
     ... return otherwise.
     // do some things to initialize the drag.
     ...
     // you might want to prevent the click to bubble / trigger default behaviour :
     e.stopPropagation();
     e.preventDefault();
 }
```

you set it up once and for all on the window or document object :

```
document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleMouseDown)
```

I made a tiny demo here, click on a div to see that it has been identified :
http://jsbin.com/ilavikI/2/edit

Comment: Yes, this was exactly what was happening. What I don't like about this solution is that each instance will hold then a new reference to the function, thus largely increasing the footprint. Is there any way of avoiding this in a way that I can still bind the function? If I try to declared it using the .bind(this) from the declaration, the function is bound to the Window instead of the instance of my class, as it is the window who is actually executing the IIFE in the first place.

Comment: i edited for a solution that avoids to add/remove events listener on each click.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that your

```
 .bind(this)
```

in

```
  this._div.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDragDown.bind(this), false);
```

does not return the reference to the same function you are removing?

Comment: I definitely think that this is part of the problem/solution. I should probably keep a reference to the bound function and remove that, since the .bind most likely creates a new reference of the function with a new closure.